# How to bold only a part of a paragraph?

Tags: text, paragraph

I'm generating a document from a Google form and I want to format a certain text in the document.

This is my code:

```
//Add first paragraph (greeting)
var para1 = body.appendParagraph('Hi '+ email +', thank you for signing our 
                   Laptop Policy. Here\'s a copy for your records.\n\n');
```

I get this outcome:

> Hi name@domain.com, thank you for signing our Laptop Policy. Here's a
>   copy for your records.

But I want this outcome (email address only in bold):

> Hi **name@domain.com**, thank you for signing our Laptop Policy.
>   Here's a copy for your records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `Text` objects and you can set the bold property individually on specific runs of text:

```js
var para1 = body.appendParagraph('Hi ');

var emailText = para1.appendText(email);
emailText.setBold(true);

para1.appendText(', thank you for signing our Laptop Policy. Here\'s a copy for your records.\n\n');
```

If you merely had text in an existing paragraph, you could also just style parts of it (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setBold(Integer,Integer,Boolean)):

```js
var text = somePara.editAsText();
text.setBold(5, 15, true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, dtanabe!!